# How to catch white screen or black screen using robotframework or selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, robotframework

My project is to catch certain error message that can possibly show on website using robot framework and selenium. such as 400 - 500 error messages.

ex:

404.  page not found

But we cannot catch empty page like white screen or black screen.

Is there a way for robot/selenium to tell if the page is just all white or all black ? whith no text visible or any element visible.

Thanks

Comment: Can you verify that an expected text or element is on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Just get the source and check any unique text or tag and use it in the place of "application-footer". In my case i used application-footer which is available in my source. So Use this below code to find blank page, this is the workaround I used

```
    ${Source}=    Get Source
    Log    ${Source}
    ${Blank_status} =    Run Keyword And Return Status    Should Contain    ${Source}    application-footer
    Run Keyword If     "${Blank_status}" == "False"     FAIL    Displayed Empty Page
```

If you want to Handle Failure in your own way, then instead of FAIL keyword write your own keyword to Handle and call the keyword

```
Run Keyword If    "${Blank_status}" == "False"         Error_Handle

*** Keywords ***
Error_Handle
# write your handling code
```